# Create React App - Out of the box coverage is not 100%

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

Create react app doens't provide 100% coverage out of the box because of an index.js file that isn't tested.

I want to add precommit / prepush git hooks that prevent commits if code coverage thresholds aren't met.

How do I ignore the index.js file?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to exclude the index.js file from tests by adding the following code to the package.json file.

```
"jest": { "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/src/index.js"] }
```

Referece: [Jest - Coverage Path Ignore Patterns](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string)